# Multiple condition for Firebase query

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code for read data from Firebase with condition, but I need multiple condition. I need one more condition for read. I don't know how to do it, I founded it isn't supported, but I need it. Can me help anyone how to do it?

```
ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "project").queryEqual(toValue: "inbox").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        var newTasks = [Task]()

        for sweet in snapshot.children {
            let sweetObject = Task(snapshot: sweet as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newSweets.append(sweetObject)
        }

        self.tasks = newTasks
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error:Error) -> Void in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Data in firebase:

[image: data in firebase]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your database data?

Comment: I edit answer. It is in it.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve. Reading from the code I can see you are trying to order your `Tasks`s child nodes by their child `project`. Do you only want `Tasks` whose child node `project` equals to `"inbox"`?

Comment: @hotrod It is only one condition, but I want one more. I need more condition with read by "checked" value, but if I add one more `queryOrdered(byChild: "project").queryEqual(toValue: "inbox")` and wrote me error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. You will either have to

> **1. filter most on the server, do the rest on the client**

or

> **2. add a property that combines the values that you want to filter on**

or

> **3. create a custom index programmatically**

All these quotes come from this excellent answer over here at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase/26701282#26701282) question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user7355869 no problem! Remember that this could change in upcoming Firebase Query API updates.

Comment: It would be fine. :)